# RESTKit: NSFetchedResultsController does not populate tableView after recreating the managedObjectStore

Tags: uitableview, core-data, restkit-0.20, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I build my `TabBar` programmatically and based on if the User is loggedIn, I set 
`[self.window setRootViewController:home];`

Here is the code I call in:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
if (![Persistence loggedIn])
{
    [self showLoginScreen];
}
else
{        
    SignupBase *login = [STLoginSignupBase new];
    [login loginUserwithUsername:[Persistence username] andPassword:[Persistence authPass] requestByNewUser:NO completionBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {            
        if (!error)
        {
            [login loginSuccess];
            [self showTabBarScreen];
        }
        else
        {
            [STAlertViewUtils showAlert:@"" :error.localizedDescription :kButtonTitleDismiss];
            [self showLoginScreen];
        }
    }];
}


-(void)showTabBarScreen
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        TabBarVC *tabBarVC = [[TabBarVC alloc]init];
        [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarVC];
    });
}

-(void)showLoginScreen
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"STLoginSignup" bundle:nil];
        HomeVC *homeVC = (HomeVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[HomeVC storyboardID]];
        UINavigationController *home = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
        [self.window setRootViewController:home];
    });

}
```

In the `TabBar`, the first tab "Inbox" is a tableViewController managed with `NSFetchedResultsController`.  When I launch the app for the first time, all the objects are fetched and displayed in the tableView beautifully; however, when I logout and login back in, and "Inbox" is reloaded, I get a blank tableView.  Zero objects are fetched locally and even if RESTkit fetches objects, they don't appear in the tableView.  When I stop the app in the simulator and relaunch it, all the objects are fetched locally and remotely, and appear in the tableView as they should!

Here is how I logout from  the `Profile` tab (different tab):

```
- (void)logoutWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(void))completionBlock
{
    [Persistence setLoggedInStatus:NO];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [self getObjectManager];
    [objectManager.HTTPClient clearAuthorizationHeader];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    [managedObjectContext reset];
    [delegate deregisterWithUrbanAirship];

    if (completionBlock)
    {
        completionBlock();
    }
}
```

After I log back in the App, "Inbox" tab viewController is loaded again.

In my "Inbox" loadView which gets called, I have the following code:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [self getManagedObjectFromAppDelegate]
}

- (void)getManagedObjectFromAppDelegate
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [appDelegate setupCoreDataWithRESTKit];
    self.objectManager = [self getObjectManager];

    self.objectManager.managedObjectStore = appDelegate.managedObjectStore;
    self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = appDelegate.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
    self.managedObjectContext = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
}
```

This is the code in `[AppDelegate setupCoreDataWithRESTKit];`

```
- (RKManagedObjectStore *)setupCoreDataWithRESTKit
{

    NSError * error;
    NSURL * modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"App" ofType:@"momd"]];
    NSManagedObjectModel * managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
    self.managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    [self.managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSArray * searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString * documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSPersistentStore * persistentStore = [self.managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/App%@.sqlite", documentPath, [Persistence username]] fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:[self optionsForSqliteStore] error:&error];
    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

    NSLog(@"Path: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/App%@.sqlite", documentPath, [Persistence username]]);

    if(!persistentStore){
        NSLog(@"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);
    }

    [self.managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    return self.managedObjectStore;

}
```

Please note that each user has a different .sqlite file loaded based on their username: i.e.  AppUserName. So when I logout and log back in if it's a same user, then the same file is created/loaded.  If it's a different user, then a different name file is created/loaded.

Question: Why does `NSFetchedResultsController` displays an empty tableView after I logout and log back in, but it works fine when I launch the app the first time?

***EDIT ***

I changed and tried the code below but the problem persists:

```
- (void)logoutWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(void))completionBlock
{
    [Persistence setLoggedInStatus:NO];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [self getObjectManager];
    [objectManager.HTTPClient clearAuthorizationHeader];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    [self clearManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [delegate deregisterWithUrbanAirship];

    if (completionBlock)
    {
        completionBlock();
    }
}

- (void)clearManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
    NSFetchRequest * fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityA" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil]];
    for (id entityA in result)
    {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:entityA];
    }
    [result removeAllObjects];

    [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityB" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil]];
    for (id entityB in result)
    {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:entityB];
    }
    [result removeAllObjects];


    [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityC" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil]];
    for (id entityC in result)
    {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:entityC];
    }
    [result removeAllObjects];


    [managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing `[managedObjectContext reset];` unless you tear down the persistent store that is backing the main thread context (so, tear down the whole Core Data stack and destroy the SQLite file).

Either correct this or just loop over the things you want to delete in the context and save the changes up to the (parent) persistent context.

Comment: Thanks.  I did an `*EDIT*` to my question.  I tried the code in the edit and still have a blank tableView after logging back in.  Did I follow your advice correctly?

Comment: Code looks reasonable. You'll need to debug which SQLite files are being loaded and when, what they contain and what is being added and removed from them. You haven't shown anything about your mappings or RestKit usage, so it could be related to a conflict of unique identity parameters or bad operation configuration if you aren't using the object manager. Hard to tell.